# What's the approximate percentage of Linux servers in the world?

Tags: linux, webserver

I did so many searches on search engines, but could not find a relevant solution.

Is there any research or source that shows an approximate value for servers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are a couple of resources for Linux deployments. The best resource is likely going to be articles.

- Wikipedia topic titled: [Usage share of operating systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_operating_systems)
- [Linux Leads Server Growth - thejournal.com](http://thejournal.com/articles/2012/06/05/linux-based-systems-lead-server-growth.aspx)

If you search for "Linux server market share" or "linux servers worldwide" you'll likely find more if you need them.

*excerpt from that wikipedia topic*

#### scanning the internet

> Server market share can be measured with statistical surveys of
>   publicly accessible servers, such as web servers, mail servers or
>   DNS servers on the Internet: the operating system powering such
>   servers is found by inspecting raw response messages. This method
>   gives insight only into market share of operating systems that are
>   publicly accessible on the Internet. There will be differences in the
>   result depending on how the sample is done and observations weighted.
>   Usually the surveys are not based on a random sample of all ip
>   numbers, domain names, hosts or organisations, but on servers found by
>   some other method. Additionally many domains and ip
>   numbers may be served by one host and some domains may be served by
>   several hosts or by one host with several ip numbers.

[image: ss table #1]

> Notes:
>
> - W3Techs survey in January 2013 checked the top 1 million Web servers (according to Alexa).
> - Security Space survey in August 2009 checked 38,549,333 publicly accessible Web servers.
> - Netcraft SSL survey in January 2009 also checked 1,014,301 publicly accessible Web servers, but the survey is only valid for SSL Web servers and it is not a good measure for our purpose.

#### hardware sales method

> A method to measure the overall server market, rather than subsets
>   like publicly accessible web servers, is to count server hardware
>   sales, using data from server manufacturers. Using this method, market
>   share can be measured either in units or in revenue. In either case,
>   the measure refers to server hardware, not to software. Units refers
>   to the number of physical servers running a given OS, and revenue
>   refers to hardware revenue for physical servers running that OS. It
>   does not refer to software licensing or support revenue, which often
>   varies considerably from one OS to another.

[image: ss table #2]